# Find account GUID, and Select it back using Object GUID

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-ldap

I am trying to select a unique identifiers for accounts from Active Directory. I found that "objectguid" attribute do identify a user uniquely, but my problem is that I don't know how to convert the retrieved value into a readable format. And then be able to select a user back using this value.

I am using spring ldap libraries, right now the "objectguid" return a char[] (15 element)
So, Does any one knows any thing that can help?

(Note, I can't use SAM Name attribute)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It appears there are two string formats: `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`, which you can get via `new BigInteger(0, (byte[])attr.get()).toString(16)`, and `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`, which is the same thing plus punctuation.

Comment: Thanks EJP fro your reply, I have two problem when I tried what you have suggested: 1- attr.get() return a String containing strange symbols (ex: �'��) and when I tried to cast it to (byte[]) I get error "type mismatch can't assign non-array value to an array". I also tried to do this "attr.get().toString().getBytes()", and then ("new BigInteger(1, attr.get().toString().getBytes()"). I do get a number back but it doesn't look like a GUID. And no contacts are matching this value when I used it in search

Comment: @RO86 I expected attr.get() to return a byte[], but if it really is a String of course you can't cast it, you have to convert it. I did say to call `BigInteger.toString(16)`, and you haven't done that.

Comment: When I tried to create BigInteger with first parameter = 0 I get "java.lang.NumberFormatException: signum-magnitude mismatch" So, I used "1". Now I get in return a number , when I use this number to search for a contact (ex: (objectguid=4c3f722f6f2d5b222f3f37143f3f)) I get nothing in return. I am afraid that this "attr.get().toString().getBytes()" corrupts the guid value

Comment: @RO86 Let's backtrack. 1 is correct for the first parameter of new BigInteger, but you don't need toString() if it already is a String, and the original 'can't assign non-array value to an array' error is also curious. What was the *actual* code you wrote in response to my first suggestion? and did it *agree* with my first suggestion?

Comment: I used toString(), because "get" returns an Object, And I knew it was of type String while debugging. My problem is in searching back on the AD with "objectguid" value and get corresponding contact. If the attr.get() method returned the follwoing:                     new String(new char[]{101, 118, 26, 9, 65533, 41, 65533, 76, 65533, 106, 75, 0, 65533, 77, 29, 65533})                                Can you till me how to use this in searching back AD ?

Comment: @RO86 hold on. If it's a String you can *cast* it, no need to call toString(). Did you try the second format above?

Comment: I gave up EJP, I found another work around I have used another attribute that should be unique in our environment. Thanks for your help